# Directly copy some Pelican templates to output folder

Tags: jinja2, pelican

I have a few new templates in my pelican theme (a growing number of them, really). They are html files that hold simple web maps. I use these by `{% include %}`ing them after the content of a blog post. I place the path to the `webmap1.html` template in the markdown metadata, and then in `article.html` I `{% include %}` the web map html at the bottom of the file.

Thing is, I really would like to have these html files available as standalone html in my output as well. Initially I thought I'd be able to do this by placing `webmap1.html` in my content directory and using STATIC_PATHS to copy it to the output. However, I was unable to get the include statement to find an html file that is not within the theme/templates directory.

I also found that adding `/theme/templates/maps` or `../theme/templates/maps` to STATIC_PATHS didn't work.

Of course, one way to do this would be to include identical files in both the content directory and the template directory, but that seems sloppy. Alternatively, I could add a command to `pelican` to copy the files from one place to another before the generation happens. Looking for an alternative solution though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out I was outsmarting myself with this. All I needed to do was use the

```
DIRECT_TEMPLATES = [
    r'maps/webmap1',
]
```

setting in `pelicanconf.py`. That way, I can `{% include 'maps/webmap1.html' %}` in a separate template, and also write it to its own standalone location in the output directory.